# XSD Para Classe C# Enum

Tags: c#, xml, classes, enums, xsd

Estou gerando uma classe com o XSD.EXE a partir de uma schema. Estou resumindo o postando somente a parte do schema que gera o enum que tenho duvida.

```
<xs:simpleType name="TCodUfIBGE">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Tipo Código da UF da tabela do IBGE</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="11"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="12"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="13"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="14"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="15"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="16"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="17"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="21"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="22"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="23"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="24"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="25"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="26"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="27"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="28"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="29"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="31"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="32"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="33"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="35"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="41"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="42"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="43"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="50"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="51"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="52"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="53"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Na classe está ficando da seguinte forma:

Obs: Também resumido.

```
 public enum TCodUfIBGE
 {

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("11")]
    Item11,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("12")]
    Item12,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("13")]
    Item13,
 }
```

Exemplo:

```
 /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("11")]
    Item11 = 11,
```

Ou então:

```
public enum TipoPessoa
{
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("1")]
    Fisica = 1,
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("2")]
    Juridica = 2
}
```

**EDIT:**
Existe alguma forma de gerar esta classe com os valores referente aos itens do enum definido iguais aos do atributo?

Por que em uma aplicação real isso seria absurdo ?

Comment: Isso é um exercício né? Numa aplicação real seria absurdo esse tipo de informação ficar no código.

Comment: Não é para uma aplicação, estou fazendo varias gambiarras com o XSD.EXE para ver como ele funciona.

Comment: Ah bom, se é exercício/treino beleza. Por um instante achei meio estranho.

Comment: @Bacco, vou editar e adicionar essa questão que você comentou.

Comment: Só pra adiantar, numa aplicação real se você deixa uma tabela de código do IBGE _hardcoded_ no seu sistema, você precisa recompilar o código cada vez que muda algo. Se consultar do DB, pode atualizar a qualquer momento, e ter até uma interface para editar estes dados no DB.

Comment: @Bacco, entendi. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Baixou esse schema do site da `NFe` Correto?

Comment: Sim, do próprio portal de nfe, http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu resolvi o problema da seguinte maneira.
Quando se abre o `schema` no `VS` nota-se alguns problemas de referencia:

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

De alguma maneira esse problema de `FileioPermission` afeta a geração da classe pelo `xsd (xsd xmldsig-core-schema_v1.01.xsd nfe_v3.10.xsd /c)`

Para contornar o problema é necessário `desbloquear`o arquivo e remover a permissão `somente leitura` (fiz isso todos os arquivos de shcema)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Agora pode gerar a classe novamente (`xsd xmldsig-core-schema_v1.01.xsd nfe_v3.10.xsd /c`) e verá que é possível definir os tipos que antes não eram reconhecidos conforme a imagem:

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Fonte:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134352/how-do-i-modify-my-settings-to-allow-vs2010-to-load-3rd-party-xsd-files-from-the

Comment: Era exatamente esse o problema. Muito obrigado por ajudar.