# Valor de Enum C#

Tags: c#, enums

Tenho uma dúvida referente ao seguinte trecho de código:

```
public enum TipoPessoa
{
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("1")]
Fisica = 1,
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("2")]
Juridica = 2
}
```

ou esse:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("11")]
Item11 = 11,
```

Tenho lido em algumas perguntas isto é um absurdo.

O que está errado nestes trechos de código?

Comment: Nunca usei isso [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("1")] em um enum

Comment: Onde você leu que isso é um absurdo?

Comment: @jbueno provavelmente ele leu um comment meu em outra postagem, num contexto completamente diferente (com dados de regra de negócio), e perguntou aqui (mas não tenho certeza) - Seria bom o Reis colocar um link pra lá se for esse o caso, pra dar mais contexto. Segue link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/154069/xsd-para-classe-c-enum#comment318055_154069

Comment: Eu cheguei a pensar nisso depois que vi seu comentário na outra postagem @Bacco

Comment: Seria bom o Reis66 colocar o contexto e explicar o que ele deseja. Minha resposta foi baseada no que parece ser o que ele perguntou. A afirmação de que é um absurdo não é sobre o uso do atributo de serialização, mas do uso da enumeração. Por isso a resposta mais votada me parece não ser sobre o que a pergunta está falando. Como a pergunta não tem contexto todo mundo se confundiu.

Comment: É um direito do AP aceitar a resposta que quiser, mas parece que a pergunta não está clara mesmo. A pergunta fala em "valor do enum". A resposta aceita fala sobre atributo associado ao `enum`. A pergunta pede esclarecimento sobre o que faz isso ser ruim informando que outras respostas citavam isso. A resposta aceita não fala sobre isso. A pergunta ficou bem confusa. Aparentemente a pergunta não queria saber de fato o que foi perguntado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Tenho lido em algumas perguntas isto é um absurdo. O que está errado nestes trechos de código?

Nada. Não sei o que é tão absurdo nas respostas que anda lendo.

A única coisa que essa decoração faz é forçar o serializador XML a utilizar os valores indicados, ao invés de usar a representação `string` do valor do `enum`.

Answer (score 3):

## Constantes

Uma enumeração é uma sequência de constantes. Em geral [constantes devem ter seu estado imutável por todo ciclo de vida do projeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21997/101) (as respostas nessa pergunta dão os detalhes). Eventualmente você pode adicionar algo novo no final, mas não mais que isso, mesmo assim isso nem sempre funciona bem, mesmo que muito bem documentado.

Se um dado pode ser modificado, mesmo que entre versões da aplicação o ideal é que não seja seja constante de fato, é [melhor que seja apenas imutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151721/101).

[π (Pi)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) é uma constante. Um código que depende de uma legislação não é uma constante. É um dado que no máximo não se altera durante a execução da aplicação, mas não durante todo o ciclo de vida do projeto, ele não é constante.

Dados que não são constantes já são problemáticos quando são tratados como se fossem. Fica mais complicado quando essas constantes estão em sequência. Fica mais difícil garantir o estado.

Enumerações são mecanismos de programação. Não mecanismos de compilação. Não servem para validar regras de negócio.

Esse exemplo pega parâmetros e os transforma em constantes. Grande erro.

Tem mais uma [pergunta que fala sobre o abuso do `enum` em banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81801/101).

## Controle do dado

Então uma enumeração tem que ser algo que você tem controle, que sabe que não irá mudar.

O tipo da pessoa se é jurídica ou física é algo interno seu? Você pode garantir que seja sempre isso? Não afeta nada externo? Então nenhum problema em fazer.

Ou é algo definido por legislação? Não há garantias que a legislação não vai mudar? Se você não tem controle, não opte por algo constante. Faça algo que explicitamente indique que pode mudar. Use uma estrutura de dados propícia para mudança. Mesmo que nunca mude, isso será um acaso, a semântica do dado é que ele pode ser mudado, então represente ele de forma apropriada.

O mesmo vale para o `Item11`. Não tem contexto do que seja ele, mas parece ser algo que depende de legislação (a pergunta está sem contexto, muita gente não vai entender que [o original fala em NFe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154069/101) ([tem um caso pior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153789/101)).

A melhor explicação para isso é o tal do `ID` que todo mundo usa em banco de dados. Porque você usa um `ID` e não o CPF da pessoa, por exemplo? Porque nada garante que essa pessoa não vá trocar o CPF. Você cria um [dado substituto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) para se referenciar àquilo. Você não usa o CPF porque não tem controle sobre isso. O mesmo vale para um código de produto do fornecedor, e-mail, ou coisas do tipo.

## Mudanças

Se mudar e sua aplicação foi feita pensando que esses dados são constantes será um pesadelo dar manutenção nisso. Uma mudança pequenininha na legislação (e já houve mudança que alterou **tudo**) pode fazer com que todo o sistema pare de funcionar e para arrumar terá que refazê-lo.

Pode ser pior, uma mudança passar desapercebida. Pode parecer que está funcionando mas está gerando resultado todo errado. Imagine uma troca de ordem. Quando os dados podem mudar você precisa ter uma referência canônica dele dentro do seu sistema que não dependa de informações externas.

Faça o sistema preparado para mudanças.

## Conceito correto

As pessoas precisam entender que sistemas não precisam apenas "funcionar". Eles precisam estar conceitualmente certos para suportar a manutenção futura. Se um dado faz parte de uma tabela mutável, represente-o como uma tabela mutável. Escolha um [dicionário](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) ou outra estrutura de dados mais adequada para isso. Pode até criar uma estrutura própria se for benéfico. Mas não use uma estrutura constante.

Note que esses dicionários possivelmente serão preenchidos com dados vindos do banco dedados. Ou até o banco de dados será usado para fornecer o que precisa de forma direta.

O fato de usar `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("11")]` já mostra que é o mecanismo errado. O dado real é um texto. Uma enumeração não representa textos, ela representa números. Isso é uma tentativa de arrumar o erro inicial. E é mais um erro. Daí concluímos que erros atraem erros. Só fica pior.

Nem falei sobre a [legibilidade do código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13890/101). Acha que uma enumeração chamada `TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS00CST` serve para alguma coisa no código? Alguém consegue dizer do que se trata sem medo de errar?